# Can not select UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to select a row when the table view is loaded. I've found other thread regarding this issue but they didn't solve my problem so I am asking again.

My tableview contains 5 row. And I am doing this:

```
if ([[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:self.status]) {
    [self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I've also tried `cell.selected = YES;` and `cell.highlighted = YES;`.

I am using the following code for custion selection view:

```
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0
                                                      green:138/255.0
                                                       blue:171/255.0
                                                      alpha:0.5];
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;
```

Please help me selecting a row programmatically. The row is selected when I tap on the row, but can not select programmatically.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is a delegate method.

Answer (score 3):

Try with following code

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Here you need to set `indexPath` for row that you want to be selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this by calling `UITableView` delegate method which is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

inside this method you need to check every selected time that same cell are you not tapped.

```
if ([[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:self.same]) 
{
    [myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling selectRowAtIndexPath on the table view object:

```
if ([[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:self.status]) 
{
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```